# Mysql count totals multiple items by condition left join

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to wrap my head around how to achieve the following without writing 5 or more database queries and 10 IF statements for each

I have Red, Blue and Green Widgets rated from 1-10 how do I display how many of each are in the database? ie

**Red Widgets:**

- 6 rated a 1
- 12 rated a 2
- 30 rated a 3

etc

and the same for the Blue and Green as well?

```
$sql = "SELECT UNIT.type, UNIT.condition, COUNT(1) AS count LEFT JOIN UNITS ON SITE.id=UNIT.id WHERE SITE.name='name' GROUP BY UNIT.type, UNIT.condition";
```

Comment: You are missing a `FROM` in your query.

Comment: you are correct, in my actual file I do have FROM SITE